# loop deleting every i rows of every i column in r

Tags: r, function, loops, for-loop

I have a data frame of probabilities I have made with a random forest model.  I now need to clean up the data frame to keep only the first 3 rows of the first column, then the next 3 rows of the second column, and then the last 3 rows of the third column.  I am new to R and have tried basic for loops but what I need to do seems to advanced for a basic for loop.  Can anyone help?
This is the process I need the data to go through.

```
X1      X2      X3          X1      X2      X3         X1
0.672   0.012   0           0.672   NA      NA         0.672
0.636   0.066   0.002       0.636   NA      NA         0.636
0.68    0.018   0.016       0.68    NA      NA         0.68
0.716   0.028   0.044       NA      0.028   NA         0.716
0.628   0.024   0.002   --> NA      0.0024  NA    -->  0.628
0.662   0.006   0.024       NA      0.006   NA         0.006
0.716   0.016   0.022       NA      NA      0.022      0.016
0.636   0.004   0.122       NA      NA      0.122      0.004
0.848   0.014   0.01        NA      NA      0.01       0.014
```

In reality the data frame is much bigger and I will be doing this for every 200 rows.

Comment: You could try: `df[cbind(1:nrow(df), rep(1:3, each = 3))]`

Comment: You could do `indx <- cbind(1:nrow(df2), rep(1:3, each=3)) ;
indx1 <- which(!is.na(df2), arr.ind=TRUE);
df2[indx1[!do.call(paste, as.data.frame(indx1)) %in% do.call(paste, as.data.frame(indx)),]] <- NA`

Comment: @docendodiscimus I like your answer because it's simple, but when I try to expand it to the real df im using.  It doesnt work.  The real df has 2800 rows and 14 columns.  So I need to keep every 200 rows for each column.  I'm not quite sure how rep works, but when I try     df[cbind(1:nrow(df), rep(1:200, each = 14))] it errors.  Also errors when i try df[cbind(1:nrow(df), rep(1:200, each = 200))] it errors.

Comment: @BenHansen I think it should be `df[cbind(1:nrow(df), rep(1:14,each=200))]`, but to get the output as you showed, you have to do some additional modifications.

Comment: @docendodiscimus I figured it out.  For my real df, I do df[cbind(1:nrow(df), rep(1:14, each = 200))]. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You could try

```
 lst <- split(seq_len(nrow(df2)),as.numeric(gl(nrow(df2), 3, nrow(df2))))

 df2[] <- Map(function(x,y) replace(x, which(!seq_along(x) %in% y),
                            NA) , df2, lst)

 df2
 #     X1    X2    X3
 #1 0.672    NA    NA
 #2 0.636    NA    NA
 #3 0.680    NA    NA
 #4    NA 0.028    NA
 #5    NA 0.024    NA
 #6    NA 0.006    NA
 #7    NA    NA 0.022
 #8    NA    NA 0.122
 #9    NA    NA 0.010
```

#### data

```
 df2 <- structure(list(X1 = c(0.672, 0.636, 0.68, 0.716, 0.628, 
 0.662, 
 0.716, 0.636, 0.848), X2 = c(0.012, 0.066, 0.018, 0.028, 0.024, 
 0.006, 0.016, 0.004, 0.014), X3 = c(0, 0.002, 0.016, 0.044, 0.002, 
 0.024, 0.022, 0.122, 0.01)), .Names = c("X1", "X2", "X3"),
 row.names = c(NA, -9L), class = "data.frame")
```